# How to remove the following outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, outliers

I have this data below and I am just practicing on how to remove the outliers from data:

[image: My_Data]

So, After inspecting my data, I found it has no missing or duplicated values, but it has a lot of outliers as shown from the figure below:

[image: Data_visualization]

So, I have drawn the boxplot for my fund_A as shown below:

[image: fund_A]

Then, I applied IQR method as shown in this piece of code below:

```
Q1 = bank['fund_A'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = bank['fund_A'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
lower_lim = Q1 - 1.5*IQR
upper_lim = Q3 + 1.5*IQR
outliers_15_low = (bank['fund_A'] < lower_lim)
outliers_15_up = (bank['fund_A'] > upper_lim)
len(bank['fund_A']) - (len(bank['fund_A'][outliers_15_low])+len(bank['fund_A'][outliers_15_up]))
bank['fund_A'][(outliers_15_low|outliers_15_up)]
bank['fund_A'][~(outliers_15_low|outliers_15_up)]
```

Then, when I replot my data, it still has some outliers as shown below:

[image: fund_A_replot]

May you please guide me? Am I on the right track? How to remove it completely? and Do I need to apply the same procedure for others? I am a beginner to such topic.

Comment: Is it possible that it is happening because the upper and lower limit of this new dataframe changed, hence new elements, which were not outlier earlier but are now appeared?

Answer (score 1):

Let check if fund_A column may contain too small and too large values compared to others value.
Try to get those values and removed them if possible or normalize them.

We can help in a better way if we get the dataset or that column itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **a lot** of outliers, then try **not** to think of those as outliers...

Well, I understand that you are doing this for practice purposes. I think you should try a few scaling techniques on this data and then see its impact

Best of Luck